# Google Map's Polygon with hole went wrong when zoom level is bigger than 19

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Android Google Map v2 and MapFragment to display a map. I cover the whole map with a  large polygon with a small hole. It works fine when the zoom level is smaller 19, but after the zoom level goes up to 20, the hole is gone. Is it a Google Map's bug?

LatLng = (0, 0)
[image]

LatLng = (25.00, 121.52)
[image]

LatLng = (25.00, 121.52) MapType = SATELLITE
[image]

Here is my code, please help. Thanks!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
    drawPolygonWithHole(map);
}

private void drawPolygonWithHole(GoogleMap map) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> hole = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    hole.add(new LatLng(-0.0002, -0.0002));
    hole.add(new LatLng(-0.0002, 0.0002));
    hole.add(new LatLng(0.0002, 0.0002));
    hole.add(new LatLng(0.0002, -0.0002));

    map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(85,90), new LatLng(85,0.1),
             new LatLng(85,-90), new LatLng(85,-179.9),
             new LatLng(0,-179.9), new LatLng(-85,-179.9),
             new LatLng(-85,-90), new LatLng(-85,0.1),
             new LatLng(-85,90), new LatLng(-85,179.9),
             new LatLng(0,179.9), new LatLng(85,179.9))
        .addHole(hole)
        .strokeWidth(0)
        .fillColor(Color.BLACK));
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I have this issue on Android 5.0.2 on my Sony Z1 and Galaxy S4.

Comment: Ah, no. Maybe you should report this bug. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure looks like an issue within Google Maps Android API v2. There are bugs reported on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2) with a possibly same root cause, but there is nothing like this reported AFAIK, so I suggest to go there and post it.